# Why would bash string comparison stop equating to true

Tags: java, bash, solaris

I have a java config file with the following entry

```
Success=true
```

All of a sudden this comparison does not seem to equate to Boolean true .

```
if [ "$Success" == "true" ];then
//do something
fi
```

I've checked for Windows line endings  and spaces. This is bash 5.0.17, which is fairly new. Its running on Solaris. Seems simple enough and we don't want to edit the script if at all possible. What can be other explanations ?

Comment: What does `set -xv` show?

Comment: I don't really see how Java is immediately relevant. How does the entry from the config make it into the variable `$Success`? It's not just magic. Something is parsing the lines, splitting it into key and value, etc. You need to show the code that does that, or else explain what library is doing it.

Answer (score 1):

Using == for comparison is allowed but [not standard](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-6.html).

- Use the = operator with the test [ command.
- Use the == operator with the [[ command for pattern matching.

So the fix could like that:

```
if [ "$Success" = "true" ]; then
//do something
fi
```

or

```
if [[ "$Success" == "true" ]]; then
  //do something
fi
```